# How do I fix this script that I've written?

Tags: sql

I'm getting error codes every time I change just a piece of my code. I'm trying to run a statement that will count the number of CADS.
Error message ~ "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'"
Also, trying to add a Group by dbo.uneTablePTX.PropertyName
When I remove the count function my query will run flawlessly

```
select dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_name, dbo.uneTablePTX.PropertyName, (SELECT count(*) 
from dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_id  AS "TotalAccounts"
from dbo.ptx_CADS
Inner Join dbo.uneTablePTX on dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_id=dbo.uneTablePTX.cad_id
Group bydbo.uneTablePTX.PropertyName
```

I expect the columns name to change and for it to add them up. I don't understand the error message.

Comment: The error message is in the line: `from dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_id` You cannot use a field as a table. You are also missing the close parenthesis on the misplaced sub query. You are also missing a space in: `Group by dbo.uneTablePTX.PropertyName`

Comment: Fixed that, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Inner'. now

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a basic aggregation query:

```
select c.cad_name, p.PropertyName, count(*) as TotalAccounts
from dbo.ptx_CADS c Inner Join
     dbo.uneTablePTX p
     on c.cad_id = p.cad_id
group by c.cad_name, p.PropertyName;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could you help me with my format though? I don't understand all the allies very well yet.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is probably best, but I noticed you're missing a closing parenthesis in there as well, that could be part of the error message issue.

Comment: It's giving me an error at this line - from dbo.ptx_CADS

Comment: You're using a From clause directly after another From clause. I'm assuming you meant to put a closing parenthesis after "TotalAccounts" to close up the count. You also shouldn't need the quotations for TotalAccounts as per Gordon's answer.

Comment: I adjusted that and the error moved to Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Inner'.

select dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_name, dbo.uneTablePTX.PropertyName, (select count(*) from dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_id  AS TotalAccounts)
Inner Join dbo.uneTablePTX on dbo.ptx_CADS.cad_id=dbo.uneTablePTX.cad_id

Comment: Sorry m8, I didn't see your comment!